# C# Error creating directory in SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData on Windows 7 as a non Admin

Tags: c#, windows-7

I'm getting the error "Access to the path 'LocalApplicationData\MyProgram\' is denied." when trying to create a directory for my log file. This is when I'm running the program as a non-admin user.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData + "\\MyProgram\\");
```

Why would this be?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`LocalApplicationData` is just an enum value. You will have to use it in combination with [`GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx):

```
string folder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), 
    "MyProgram");
```

Answer (score 12):

You're trying to access the enumeration value `LocalApplicationData` as if it were a string.  It's not.  You need to find the folder path with `GetFolderPath`:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

Incidentally, it's better form, and less error-prone, to use `Path.Combine` to build up paths, rather than doing it by hand:

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\", "dir"); // gives you "C:\dir"
```

...and so your code would end up looking like:

```
string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath
    (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string path = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "MyProgram");
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```